# setInterval jQuery run first time without waiting for N secs

Tags: jquery

I'm setting an interval in Jquery but I want that first time it should process the set of lines of code inside the function directly without waiting for N secs and then after it should process after N secs.

Currently I'm doing like this, which waits for N secs for the first time.

```
function abc(){
    $.ajax({

    });

    setInterval(function(){
        $.ajax({

        });
    },5000);
}
```

How Do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like

```
function abc() {
    $.ajax({

    });

    function ajax() {
        $.ajax({

        });
    }

    setInterval(ajax, 5000);
    ajax()
}
```

Using setTimeout()

```
function abc() {
    $.ajax({

    });

    function ajax() {
        $.ajax({

        }).always(function () {
            setTimeout(ajax, 5000);
        });
    }

    setTimeout(ajax, 5000);
    ajax()
}
```

Comment: I would use setTimeout in the success of the Ajax, in case the return was slower than the interval

Comment: @mplungjan - Can you please provide a demo. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @ArunPJohny - It worked. Can you please have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19742479/how-do-i-dynamically-update-the-range-inside-a-gauge-highcharts) as well. Have been waiting for so long. Thanks